# how to get UTC time of a past date using asp.net and c# or sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, timezone, timezone-offset

Can you guide me to get utc time of a given date (which can be either in the past,current time). Let us say user enters the date in the format of 12-AUG-2013 17:10 PHT. Is it possible to get the UTC time of that given date? I am using asp.net and c# 3.5 and sql server 2008 for my project. Please suggest me ways to implement this option. Please let us know for more information regarding my query. Thanks

PHT is not part of the input string, but i append it to display that its Phillines time zone. But i get this abbrevations from admin screen where the country,timedifference to UTC/GMT and abbrevations of time zone are stored.

I would give the details of my requirement. User enters a date of his/her local time zone. This date can be the date in past or current one. For example, user is entering the date 12-AUG-2013 17:10  which is a phillipines date and time (Let us say). I want this date to be converted to UTC/GMT date and time. How i do it is, I ask admin user to store time difference for each country. when the user enters the date and based on the selected country, i decide it as phillipnes date and time if the user has selected country Phillipines.Then i add or substract that timedifference to get the UTC/GMT date. My concern is if user enters the date and time of a past time, then how can we get the UTC time of that date because we can only get the current UTC time. Hope I could give you enough details. I know the code and able to google and all but i need good approach to do this. I just need concept to do it.

Comment: Have you *tried* anything at all yet?  Did you look in to `DateTime.Parse`, and `TimeZoneInfo` classes?  Have you read the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)?  Are you actually wanting it to understand that "PHT" is the time zone?  Is that part of the input string?  If so, do you need to support other abbreviations as well?

Comment: Please check my edits in the question. I have given the details. hope that might help you to help me:)

Answer (score 1):

> ... i get this abbreviations from admin screen where the country, time difference to UTC/GMT and abbreviations of time zone are stored...

If you are trying to support the majority of the world, that won't be sufficient.  A time zone is not just an offset from UTC.  In most cases, you can't just ask the user for the offset.  Please read [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  You need to know what the *time zone* is.  In this case it's either `"Singapore Standard Time"` for the Windows time zone database, or `"Asia/Manila"` for the IANA database.

> For example, user is entering the date 12-AUG-2013 17:10 which is a Philippines date and time (Let us say). I want this date to be converted to UTC/GMT date and time.

Here's how you convert with C# for the Windows time zone:

```
DateTime local = new DateTime(2013, 8, 12, 17, 10, 0);
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Singapore Standard Time");
DateTime utc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(local, tz);
```

And here's how you could convert it using the IANA database, via the [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library:

```
LocalDateTime local = new LocalDateTime(2013, 8, 12, 17, 10, 0);
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Asia/Manila"];
ZonedDateTime zdt = local.InZoneLeniently(tz);
Instant utcinstant = zdt.ToInstant(); // for a NodaTime instant
DateTime utcdt = zdt.ToDateTimeUtc(); // for a regular UTC DateTime
```

I skipped over the fact that you are starting with a string since your question is more focused on the UTC and time zone issue.  If you need help on that, look at [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.Parse.aspx) or [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx).  If you go with Noda Time, look at [their text parsing docs](http://nodatime.org/1.1.x/userguide/text.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
 DateTime utcDateTime = DateTimeVariable.ToUniversalTime();
```

Comment: what if the user provides a last year date and how to get the exact UTC time of that date.

Comment: pass date in DateTimeVariable

Comment: @Uneverno http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495915.aspx  check  this link

Comment: can you give an example pls?